# Value of Variable Not Updating

Tags: java

My Variable c is always zero. I dont understand why its not updating. can anyone please explain why this is happening. what should i do to avoid this

```
public static int linearSearch(Exam[] marks, String name) {
    int c =0;
    if( marks==null)
    {

        return -1;

    }
    else{

        for(int i=0;i<marks.length;i++)
        {

            //System.out.println(a[i]);
            if(performances[i].getName()==name)
            {
                c= i;

            }

        }
    }
    return c;


    //to be completed
}
```

Comment: Because you're using `==` to compare strings, not `.equals()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify this line as below

```
performances[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)
```

if you want to Ignore upper or lower case

else use the below

```
performances[i].getName().equals(name)
```

to check the content of the name instead of references.

Comment: Should be `.equals(name)` or `.equalsIgnoreCase(name)`, **not** `.equalIgnorecase(name)` - the capital 'C' matters.